# How to extract .gtar file?

Tags: tar, gzip, gunzip

I have a `.gtar` file, I wanted to extract it, but it is not getting extracted.

Below are the methods I have tried with its output. I supposed to be contained bunch of text files.

```shellsession
$ gtar -xf file.gtar
gtar: This does not look like a tar archive.
gtar: Skipping to next header.
gtar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors.

$ gtar -xzf file.gtar
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
gtar: Child returned status 1
gtar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

$ gunzip -c file.gtar | tar xvf -
gzip: file.gtar: not in gzip format
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

$ tar -xzf file.gtar 
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

$ file file.gtar 
file.gtar: HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
```

Can anyone please suggest some method to extract it?

Comment: Please use the `file` command (e.g. `file file.gtar`) to confirm what type the file actually is

Comment: in addition to tell us what `file file.gtar` tells you, please also give an indication of what you expect this to be, i.e. where you have it from, and what you think it *should* contain. You probably have contextual knowledge we are simply lacking!

Comment: comment asking for `file` information posted 5 minutes after question was posted, then 2hrs no reaction: I'm afraid this has been abandoned :( VTC as in need of detail.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm sorry :( , I have updated now.

Comment: `HTML document, ASCII text` is a strong hint as to what it is.

Comment: `.gtar` is not a common extension for files, and files can in any case be called anything without consideration for what is in them. That's why you were asked to use `file` to find out what it actually was. Now that we can see it's HTML, we can guess that it's the result of you doing something wrong when you tried to download something, but that is what @MarcusMüller's questions were meant to uncover, so please also answer those.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity while you're right, both `file` and how OP ended up with that file would have been valid hints. But in this case, it's really useless to ponder this any further: Not a tar archive at all, hence cannot be unpacked with `tar` or anything similar. This is a HTML file. Moving on!